# Build fails when archiving React Native App in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, nvm

My build fails when attempting to archive my react native project in Xcode. The following appears when trying to archive:

[image]

Does anyone know what may be causing this error? I have tried editing the run script in 'Bundle React Native code and images' to the below as suggested by the link https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3935:

. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh

However, I'm still getting the same error. Can someone please advise? I'm really stuck here.

Thanks.

Comment: this error is cannot find the node when getting node_binary. I am ok by adding 
`export NODE_BINARY=$(which node)` before calling the .sh script

Comment: Thanks. The error still appears when changing to export NODE_BINARY=$(which node)
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh  as suggested.

Comment: Anyone know what I may need to do? I don't know what else I need to do. Is there something wrong with one of the packages I've installed? Possibly firebase? A new project seems to archive fine. I don't know what else to do